# Parent node check in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jstree as shown below:

```
$('#FolderTree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': [
                            {
                                'text': 'Claim key',
                                'state': {
                                    'opened': false,
                                    'selected': false
                                },
                                'children': claimKeys
                           },
                            {
                                'text': 'Client',
                                'state': {
                                    'opened': false,
                                    'selected': false
                                },
                                'children': clients
                            }
                         ]
                  },

            "plugins": ["checkbox"]
        });
```

For click event of checkbox I'm using the below jquery :

```
$('#FolderTree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
            var checkedValue = data.node.text;
  });
```

But I want to first determine if the checkbox I've clicked is parent node or child node..How can I do that??

Comment: I'm not familiar with jstree, but in the API it says there are `is_parent` and `get_parent` functions that might help you. http://www.jstree.com/api/#/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$('#FolderTree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var checkedValue = data.node.text;
    var isParent = data.instance.is_parent(); 
    // you can also use is_leaf() to check the opposite
});
```

`is_parent` will tell you if the node has any children, `is_leaf` will tell you if it is a leaf node (if it has no children) - use one or the other.

If you need to check if a node is a root node you can use:
`var isRoot = (data.node.parents.length === 1)`